# Paypal Freezing

Tags: onepage-checkout, paypal-express, magento2.3.4

On our site `www.mysteryfunkos.co.uk` whenever a customer is either using Facebook Browser or any other generic browser at the moment, they use `PayPal` to pay for their goods, but upon returning to our site, it freezes or says the website cannot handle the request.

We are using `One Step Checkout`, Stripe payments work no issues at all. Any advice on how to resolve it? We are using BSS Commerce for the One Step Checkout.

[image]

Comment: may be this could be the issue with the third party extension. did you checked with some other osp extension and check weather the issue still persist

Comment: We havent tried any other extension as of yet as its only recently decided to not work

Comment: see if you can give a try to this free one https://github.com/ecomteck/module-one-step-checkout-compatible

Comment: thanks for that, i will have a look, looking into the Backend, could it be conflicting information. On the Configuration-Checkout- we have enabled one page checkout. Then looking at the Configuration-BSS-One Step Checkout, that is enabled aswell

Comment: when i disable the one step checkout, the cart doesnt load but when i disable the BSS Commerce, it reverts back to Magentos standard checkout format

Comment: What about the Memory on the site, with it saying it cannot handle the request?

Comment: i dont think this is related to memory but the chances are more that this could be due to one your third party extension that you might have recently integrated